# Compress svg and compression in the server

Tags: svg

I tried Compressed plain SVG (.svgz) the files are smaller and it looks the same than the regular .svg. Is there any downside? Can I use always .svgz?

On the other side, on the server I use a compression deflate with a code in the .htaccess. Could that affect the svgz? If I use deflate, does it matter if I use svg or svgz?

Comment: That sounds a bit like OT, have you looked at [superuser](https://superuser.com/)/[serverfault](https://serverfault.com/) sites?

Comment: There should be no difference between automatically deflating an SVG, and serving an .svgz. Other than the CPU resources for doing the compression of course.  .svgz is just a gzipped SVG file.